# Swift - Draw on UIView in new thread

Tags: ios, iphone, multithreading, swift, uiview

I've got a UIView. In function **drawRect()** I'm drawing a grid on it (vertical and horizontal lines). When I run my app on iPhone 4S - fps is not high enough. Without interface everything is pretty good, but if there is something else on the screen - fps falling down.

I optimized drawing function as much as I could. For example I'm not using **CGContextAddLineToPoint()**. Instead of it I'm drawing lines using **CGContextStrokeRect()**, because as I could see - the last one works faster.

Anyway - app still works not fast enough. iPhone 4S and new models have few graphics cores, so I think, that I can speed up my app by drawing grid in another thread

I tried to make it like that

```
override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
    let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
    let screenScale = self.window!.screen.scale
    let queue = NSOperationQueue()

    queue.addOperationWithBlock() {
        drawGrid(context, rect: rect, screenScale: screenScale)
    }
}
```

But for some reason drawn grid is twice smaller then must to be.

So what am I doing wrong and can I draw on UIView in separate thread using Swift?
Please, help me to find out.

Comment: AFAIK all UI operations have to be done on the main thread don't they?

Comment: You may be able to use CoreGraphics from different threads in very limited situations but the context UIKit hands you in `-drawRect:` is valid only in `-drawRect:`.  Don't try to race UIKit, you'll always lose.

Comment: @CodaFi so there is no way to draw grid in another thread?

Comment: Not saying you can't, just saying it will be a challenge.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a png image instead of manually drawing everything. Get more information [here.](http://robots.thoughtbot.com/designing-for-ios-graphics-performance)

> Customizing... with a UIImage background relies entirely on
>   the GPU for rendering the image assets saved on disk.

...

> The drawRect method relies on Core Graphics to do the custom drawing,
>   but its main drawback lies in the way it handles touch events: each
>   time the button is pressed, setNeedsDisplay forces it to redraw; not
>   only once, but twice for every single tap. This is not a good use of
>   CPU and memory...